# Laravel 6.4.1 + webpack + vue + scss dynamically loaded

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-6

I have laravel 6.4.1 with minor changes to the default webpack config.
I'm using vue components with scoped styling as well.

When I run `npm run dev`, everything works as it should. My Vue component is loaded and has styling.
When I run `npm run production`, my Vue component is not loaded.
Or well... The JS file is loaded, but the component never fires `created` or `mounted` and is not visible on screen and not visible in the DOM.

**How do I know it's loaded then?**

When I put `console.log('test')` above (or below) the `export default` it is displayed in the console.

When I remove the `<style scoped lang="scss">` tag completely, my component is visible on screen as well.

I've already tried deleting parts of the styling, but it never works. Even an empty style tag will not render the component. It will only work when I fully remove it.

Ofcourse, I want to keep my styling in the component, so how can I fix this problem?

I've removed some JS from the Vue component to make it more readable and since I strongly suspect the issue in not in the JS I don't think it has any value for this issue.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
} else {
    mix.sourceMaps();
}

// webpack.mix.js
const path = require('path'),
    WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin'),
    BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin,
    {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new WebpackShellPlugin({
            onBuildStart: [
                'php artisan js-localization:export --quiet',
                'php artisan ziggy:generate resources/js/ziggy-routes.js --quiet'
            ]
        }),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: mix.inProduction() ? 'disabled' : 'server',
            openAnalyzer: false
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            dry: false,
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: [],
            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: [
                'js/chunk/*'
            ],
            dangerouslyAllowCleanPatternsOutsideProject: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/js/route.js'),
        },
    },
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunk/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    },
});
```

**Vue component**

```
<template>
    <div class="position-relative my-2" :style="{backgroundColor: properties.settings.backgroundColor}">
        <block-template-content-text
            v-if="canDisplayBlock(block, 'content', 'text')"
            :text-config="tinyMce.text"
            :block="block"
            @block-change="storeBlockChange">
        </block-template-content-text>
        <block-template-content-text-image
            v-if="canDisplayBlock(block, 'content', 'text-image')"
            :text-config="tinyMce.text"
            :image-config="tinyMce.image"
            :block="block"
            @block-change="storeBlockChange">
        </block-template-content-text-image>

        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-column position-absolute controls">
            <i class="fas fa-2x fa-fw fa-chevron-up cursor-pointer" @click="$emit('sort-item', 'up', block)"></i>
            <div>
                <i class="fas fa-1x fa-fw fa-plus-circle cursor-pointer" @click="$emit('add-new-block', block)"></i>
                <!-- delete section start -->
                <i class="fas fa-1x fa-fw fa-trash cursor-pointer"
                   :id="'delete-' + block.hash"
                   @click="$emit('delete-block', $event, block)"></i>
                <b-tooltip :target="'delete-' + block.hash"
                           :id="'tooltip-' + block.hash"
                           triggers="focus">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                            @click="$emit('cancel-delete-block', block)">
                        {{ Lang.get('general.buttons.cancel') }}
                    </button>

                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-danger"
                            @click="$emit('delete-block', $event, block)">
                        <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash"></i>
                        {{ Lang.get('general.buttons.delete')}}
                    </button>
                </b-tooltip>
                <!-- delete section end -->

                <!-- popover start -->
                <div class="popover-content" :hidden="!showPopover">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-times close-popover cursor-pointer" @click="closePopover"></i>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="background-color">
                            {{ Lang.get('project.design.pages.block.settings.background-color') }}
                        </label>
                        <input type="color"
                               name="background-color"
                               id="background-color"
                               class="form-control"
                               v-model="properties.settings.backgroundColor"
                               value="#ffffff"
                               @input="setSetting('backgroundColor', $event)">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="fas fa-1x fa-fw fa-cog cursor-pointer"
                   @click="togglePopover"></i>
                <!-- popover end -->
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-2x fa-fw fa-chevron-down sort-order cursor-pointer"
               @click="$emit('sort-item', 'down', block)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    // Bootstrap Vue
    import {TooltipPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue';
    Vue.use(TooltipPlugin);

    // TinyMCE editor
    import 'tinymce/tinymce.min';
    import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min';
    import 'tinymce/plugins/paste';
    import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
    import 'tinymce/plugins/imagetools';
    import {EventBus} from "../../vue/EventBus";

    export default {
        name: "display-block",
        components: {
            'block-template-content-text': () => import('./blocks/content/Text'),
            'block-template-content-text-image': () => import('./blocks/content/TextImage'),
        },
        props: {
            block: {
                required: true,
                type: Object
            }
        },
        data() {
           [...]
        },
        methods: {
            [...]
        },
        mounted() {
            [...]
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
    @import "../../../sass/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/position";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";

    // Bootstrap Vue
    @import '~bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';

    .block {
        .block- {
            &text {
                @import '~tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css';
                @import '~tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css';
                @import '~tinymce/skins/content/default/content.min.css';
            }
        }
    }

    .controls {
        @extend .position-relative;

        top: map_get($sizes, 50);
        right: - map_get($spacers, 5);
        transform: translateY(-50%);

        &:first-child {
            @extend .d-none;
        }

        .popover-content {
            @extend .popover;
            @extend .p-2;

            min-width: 150px;
            min-height: 150px;

            .close-popover {
                @extend .position-absolute;
                @extend .mt-2;
                @extend .mr-2;

                top: 0;
                right: 0;
            }

            input {
                &[type=color] {
                    @extend .p-0;

                    width: 25px;
                    height: 25px;
                    border: none;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

**page.js**

```
import {EventBus} from "../../vue/EventBus";
import {TooltipPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue';
// import DisplayBlock from "../../components/project/DisplayBlock";

if (document.getElementById('page-editor')) {
    // Bootstrap Vue
    Vue.use(TooltipPlugin);

    new Vue({
        el: '#page-editor',
        components: {
            BlockModal: () => import('../../components/project/BlockModal'),
            DisplayBlock: () => import('../../components/project/DisplayBlock'),
            // DisplayBlock
        },
        data: {
            [...]
        },
        computed: {
            [...]
        },
        watch: {
            [...]
        },
        methods: {
            [...]
        },
        mounted() {
            [...]
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack file the resolver is missing for VUE.

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' 
    }
  }
```

Try by adding the above snippet.

Comment: I tried but I get this message
`TypeError: Vue.mixin is not a function`

I also tried changing `esm` to `common` (the file you put in the comment) but that doesn't give any errors and does not work as well.

Should the path to `vue.esm.js` be in my `node_modules` directory?

Comment: No. Its should be like that. But where are you using the mixin.

Comment: What do you mean by `where are you using the mixin`? I placed the alias in the `webpack.mix.js` file.

Comment: Have you added the vue loader to compile the `.vue` templates. And in your webpack the vue loader is not specified.

Comment: I think this is shipped with the default laravel mix configuration for webpack. since everything works fine  with `npm run dev`?

Comment: Is the same webpack file being used for `prod` and `dev`?

Comment: Yes, I have only one webpack config file.

In my package.json it says this (laravel default):
`"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`

`"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

Comment: If you see in this statement `webpack.config.js` getting called on both prod and dev instances. So u need to find that file and make the changes in that file.

Comment: I can't since it's loaded using node_modules. It's just the css not working in the vue file. the rest is working.

Comment: try replacing webpack.config.js with `webpack.mix.js`. As this file is extending to the base webpack config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204054/discussion-between-theatreofsouls-and-ramki).